# Staking-pool core contract - ext_contract macro and callbacks

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

1. In the `internal_restake` function, why do we have to access the `on_stake_action` function as if it's an external cross contract call when its a function thats a part of the calling contract? Couldn't we just do `.then(self.on_stake_action())` instead? I'm assuming it has something to do with the face that it's a callback from `stake()` promise call.
2. In what situation would you make an interface for the contract itself like `ext_self`?
3. What does the #[ext_contract()] macro do in a nutshell?



   -------- Staking Pool Contract Code Below --------------------
   [lib.rs lines 155~162](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/master/staking-pool/src/lib.rs)

```rust
/// Interface for the contract itself.
#[ext_contract(ext_self)]
pub trait SelfContract {
    /// A callback to check the result of the staking action.
    fn on_stake_action(&mut self);
}
```

[lib.rs lines 399~421](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/master/staking-pool/src/lib.rs)

```rust
   pub fn on_stake_action(&mut self) {
        assert_eq!(
            env::current_account_id(),
            env::predecessor_account_id(),
            "Can be called only as a callback"
        );

        assert_eq!(
            env::promise_results_count(),
            1,
            "Contract expected a result on the callback"
        );
        let stake_action_succeeded = match env::promise_result(0) {
            PromiseResult::Successful(_) => true,
            _ => false,
        };

        // If the stake action failed and the current locked amount is positive, then the contract
        // has to unstake.
        if !stake_action_succeeded && env::account_locked_balance() > 0 {
            Promise::new(env::current_account_id()).stake(0, self.stake_public_key.clone());
        }
    }
```

[internal.rs lines 8~22](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/master/staking-pool/src/internal.rs)

```rust
    /// Restakes the current `total_staked_balance` again.
    pub(crate) fn internal_restake(&mut self) {
        if self.paused {
            return;
        }
        // Stakes with the staking public key. If the public key is invalid the entire function
        // call will be rolled back.
        Promise::new(env::current_account_id())
            .stake(self.total_staked_balance, self.stake_public_key.clone())
            .then(ext_self::on_stake_action(
                &env::current_account_id(),
                NO_DEPOSIT,
                ON_STAKE_ACTION_GAS,
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the "external" interface for the contract is that the call to the method is external since it is "called" as part of a promise action.

```rust
/// Interface for the contract itself.
#[ext_contract(ext_self)]
pub trait SelfContract {
    /// A callback to check the result of the staking action.
    fn on_stake_action(&mut self);
}
```

Firstly in rust procedural macros a stream of tokens (`pub`, `trait`, `SelfContract`, ...) in the input and output.  In this case the output is not a trait but rather a module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html) named `ext_self`.  Then a function `on_stake_action` is added to the module and modified with the self argument removed and three new arguments added and returns a `Promise`.

```rust
        Promise::new(env::current_account_id())
            .stake(self.total_staked_balance, self.stake_public_key.clone())
            .then(ext_self::on_stake_action(
                &env::current_account_id(),
                NO_DEPOSIT,
                ON_STAKE_ACTION_GAS,
            ));
```

Note `ext_self` is the module `::` is the path separator to access `on_stake_action` and `&env::current_account_id()` is the receiver, `NO_DEPOSIT` is the attached deposit, and `ON_STAKE_ACTION_GAS` is the gas for the promise call.  Furthermore the code for the implementation of the function is generated; it encodes the arguments to the function (in this case there aren't any) and creates a promise that calls the method `on_stake_action`.

The reason the initial declaration for this is a trait is that it doesn't require an implementation and IDE's with good rust support will already expand this macro allowing you to use `ext_self` as a module even though you can't see that that is what it is.

You raise a good point though that `ext_contract` macro treats calls to the same contract the same as others.  So perhaps a new useful feature would be to create a new macro that will already use `env::current_account_id()`.